# Showing Data visualization (charts and stats) in ReactJS UI

Tags: reactjs, django-models, google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I have a form in **ReactJS**, after submit, form data is posted to **Django** backend.

My requirement is, I need to run data analysis and visualization on submitted form data, with data already exists from  previous submitted data.

can I build data visualization in Django Rest Framework?. or can I do data analysis and visualization in Pandas library?. But not sure how to build an API so that I can show up these data visualization to ReactJS ui after form submit.

Or Google or Azure cloud provide api for building data visualization on cloud and expose it as an api?

Please let me know , if any sample or reference to github project, will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Can you build a data visualization app with DRF in the backend and React in the frontend?

Yes. I will briefly describe the flow.

Easy mode (with data computing on the server):

1. Submit the form in React.
2. Data is handled in DRF.
3. You do all computations in request processing. Yes, you can use any ML/Data science libraries. BUT, all computations should be quick and shouldn't use a lot of resources.
4. You return the results of your analysis as a JSON.
5. On the React side, you get the response from the server. You can display results, for example as a chart (data visualization).

The response returned from the server in point 4 can have already prepared JSON for the charting library.

For charting, I can recommend Plotly: https://plotly.com/javascript/react/ You can use plotly in Jupyter notebook as well for creating prototypes of analysis.

The difficult mode:
Your data analysis part take a lot of time and needs computing resources. Then you should use some background processing library (for example Celery). This is a little more complicated. You should do long polling on React side.

BTW, I'm working on [Django+React tutorials how to build real SaaS applications from scratch](https://saasitive.com). Would love to write about similar to yours use case in the future.

If you have more questions, feel free to ask. I'm happy to help!

Comment: Great. Interesting. I have already submitted request to join your course on saasitive.com. When the course will be ready?.

Is there any fast track :)?

Comment: Cant be fast track in programming, everything takes time ;) I will try to add a visualization article next month. The course (how to build your own Django+React boilerplate) should start this week and I will keep adding new articles.

Comment: I filled up form for subscribing to paid course, is it more hands on course?

Comment: For sure, there will be more advanced topics. But first I need to complete the free course.